# "No relations found" in psql after rails db:migrate succeeds

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

As a Rails novice, I'm following instructions in railscast #342 to set up a postgres database connection on my Mac.

I created a new rails project with

```
$ rails new blog -d postgresql
```

I edited the database yaml file to set the username and password.

I used psql to add the new user and password, and gave it permission to create tables:  `alter user blog create db`

I created the db via

```
rake db:create:all
```

It succeeded and inside psql, doing \l to list schemas, I see all three schemas blog_test, blog_development and blog_production

I then do

```
$ rails g scaffold article name content:text
```

all looks good

I then do

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I get messages showing success:

```
$ rake db:migrate

== 20150701220010 CreateArticles: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:articles)
   -> 0.0128s
== 20150701220010 CreateArticles: migrated (0.0129s) ==========================
```

I set my search path to look at the schema:

```
set search_path to lcuff,public,blog_development;
```

show search_path:

```
search_path
---------------------------------
 lcuff, public, blog_development
```

But trying to find the table,

```
# \d
```

No relations found.

I've done the `db:migrate VERSION=0` and it successfully reports that it drops the table, and then I create it again with `db:migrate` and it reports success.

If the first part hadn't worked, where it actually created the schema, I'd think I'm pointed to the wrong database somehow.

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should first ***connect*** to the ***database*** before fetching the tables.

```
\connect blog_development
```

And then try giving `\d` to list all tables.

You can also try with `\dt`.

***Example(Tested in my Project):***

```
\connect my_db
You are now connected to database "my_db" as user "postgres".

my_db=# \d

                    List of relations
 Schema |             Name              | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | access_managements            | table | postgres
 public | amenities                     | table | postgres
 public | city_coordinates              | table | postgres
 public | coapplicants                  | table | postgres
```

[**Source**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql)